# how to access callback function outside function

Tags: javascript

I am new to javascript. the question may look simple for you. but if you can help me.
How do I access Zval into "outside function"

```js
var zval = "";
var x = "";
var y = "";
myFunc(2, 3, function(zval) {
  console.log("inside Function  :" + zval); // 5
});

console.log("Outside function   :" + zval); // undefined
function myFunc(x, y, callback) {
  var z = x + y;
  callback(z);
};
```

Comment: return will not work here becaue i have a complex multiple function inside.   so want to access the call back variable outside og the fnction.

Comment: If you have more details to add, put them in the question, not a comment.

Comment: Normally, you don't. I mean, you shouldn't. Why are you trying to?

Comment: @Bergi,  what i am trying to do is  --   I have  a main function.  function fucn1(a){   function (b){  //do stuffs using value a. callback ()}.   now want to access that a into main function.

Comment: You have two 'zval' one the global variable and the other is an argument for a callback function! and you are accessing both of them! I cannot understand what your intent is!. can you maybe change the name of one of the zval? because they are two things with the same name

Answer (score 1):

Use a different name for the parameter than the outside variable, so it doesn't shadow the outer variable. This allow you to explicitly assign the value to the outer variable inside the function, and access it there afterwards:

```js
var zval = "";
var x = "";
var y = "";
myFunc(2, 3, function(z) {
  zval = z;
  console.log("inside Function  :" + z); // 5
});

console.log("Outside function   :" + zval); // undefined
function myFunc(x, y, callback) {
  var z = x + y;
  callback(z);
};
```

In the special case where the outer variable is a global variable, you can also use `window.zval` to refer to it.

```js
var zval = "";
var x = "";
var y = "";
myFunc(2, 3, function(zval) {
  window.zval = zval;
  console.log("inside Function  :" + zval); // 5
});

console.log("Outside function   :" + zval); // undefined
function myFunc(x, y, callback) {
  var z = x + y;
  callback(z);
};
```